# WAMP Wordpress 505 Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress, wamp, http-status-code-505

Spent way to long on this and am just running in circles. Probably just a basic stuff up but it's doing my head in.

I'm developing a Wordpress site with a custom theme. The assets contained within the theme folder are 505'ing, I'm calling my assets as such:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/art/logo.png" width="130" height="130" alt="logo" />
```

I have uncommented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And my .htaccess looks as followed:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mysite/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I completely uninstalled WAMP and reisntalled but still having the same issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Reinstalling everything never is a good idea. It never solves problems. It is only an expression of giving up.

Comment: If I was giving up why would I be seeking advice? I am merely reverting everything to the default settings to ensure that a conflict has not arisen due to trialling various methods. Please don't ever become a philosopher.

Comment: LOL, or, promised, I will not become a philosopher on my old days. What I meant is: reinstalling a software package usually does not wipe existing settings, since those are stored elsewhere, in a users home directory or similar. Reinstalling typically only replaces the binaries installed by the package. But those are not the issue in > 99,9% of all cases.

Comment: if you got an Internal Server Error, apache is loggin the details of the error(s) in: `C:\wamp\logs\php_errors.log` Can you please let us know the error